# Excel - how to apply multiple conditional designs

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight rows as a reminder based on dates. I have a due date column (ex: 13/06/2021) and a days to (ex: 21) column. Now I want the row to be colored whenever the date minus the days is today AND for it to stay colored until I check the status as done.

Comment: You are going to have to post some sample data with expected behavior.  How do you change status?  Does your days to column change?

Comment: This sounds straightforward. Do you know about the ```AND()``` function? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data will  also if you have tried any formula so far, will help us data orientation to fix it !!

Comment: How do you check the status? Welcome back to provide more information about your issue.